# How to make ruby API calls and CSV writing thread safe?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, csv, thread-safety

I'm trying to build a program that reads a large CSV file, then concurrently sends requests to an API endpoint, and finally store results to another CSV file. I've read about thread pools on this page https://blog.engineyard.com/ruby-thread-pool and also found out about the concurrent ruby gem. I figured what I am trying to achieve should be easy enough to attain without using the gem. I am using the MRI interpreter and read about the GIL. I think since this appears to be IO heavy I wouldn't need to use Jruby and a gem such as peach.  Here is what I have so far:

```
array_of_stuff = CSV.read("#{file_name}")

work_q = Queue.new

array_of_stuff.flatten.each { |x| work_q .push x }

workers = (0..4).map do 

 Thread.new { 
            begin 
            while item = work_q.pop(true) 

            uri = URI.parse("https://website.com/query=" + "#{item}")
            #create the HTTP protocol 
            http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
            #set up ssl 
            http.use_ssl = true 
            http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

            #create the request 
            req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
            req["Authorization"] = "Special #{token}"

            #create the response 
            response = http.request(req)

            if response.body == "[]\n"
            print "\nNo data for #{item}\n"
            next 
            end 

            #parse JSON response.
            data = JSON.parse(response.body) 

            puts "#{item} has some data #{data[0]["Attribute"]["value"]}"

                 print "\Storing results to a CSV file.\n"
                 CSV.open("item_store.csv", "a+") do |csv|
                 csv << ["#{item}", "#{data[0]["Attribute"]["value"]}"]
                 end 
            end 
            rescue ThreadError
            end 
   }
end 

workers.map(&:join)
```

I know this isn't working because the `puts` section of the code shows me that some requests were made multiple times. I've read up on mutex synchronize and tried that but it slowed down my code plus I am using it wrong. If anybody can help me out and clear up my misunderstanding I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Will hitting the API endpoint concurrently result in any API limits?  Most have some limitations of how many requests per second / per day you can make.

Comment: so do you know if you hit limits when trying this code?

Comment: That is a good question i do not believe so. I have tested the above code with a CSV file of about ten entries. Nowhere near the limits. Does the code appear correct? You may be on to something about the limits. Perhaps too many request a second? I added mutex.synchronize {sleep(1)} right before response = http.request(req) and I am still getting the same issue.